# Change the socket port of a server that is already running (python)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a server written in python 2.7 that executes an infinite loop and process information from port 5000. Is it possible to change this connection port without restarting the server? 
For example: the server is running in port 5000 and receives a 'change_port' option, the server module has to stop listening in port 5000 to start listening in port 7000. I don't know if i can manipulate sockets like that... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once you have bound a socket to an address (interface, port) it cannot be changed. However, you can create a new socket (or many, depending on your needs) and bind it to your address (interface, port).
The code will differ based on the transport layer protocol you're using:

TCP:

```
# 1) Create first socket
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.bind(('0.0.0.0',5000))
# 2) Create second socket
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.bind(('0.0.0.0',7000))

# 3) Wait for a connection on the first socket
s1.listen(5)
sc, address = s1.accept()

# 4) Once a connection has been established...
# send, recv, process data
# until you need the next socket

# 5) Open connection on second socket
s2.listen(1)
sc2, address2 = s2.accept()
# now it probably a good time to tell the client (via s1) that s2 is ready
# client connects to s2
```

There you go

UDP (almost the same):

```
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s1.bind(('0.0.0.0',5000))
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s2.bind(('0.0.0.0',7000))
data, addr = s1.recvfrom(256)
s1.sendto("s2 ready",addr)
data2, addr2 = s2.recvfrom(256)
```

Simplified, but that's all there really is to it.
You might consider verifying that the address of the client from s1 is the same as the client connecting to s2.

Answer (score 1):

No, it seems that you cannot run the socket.bind() method when its already bound. However, I have a solution you can use with the Asyncore module.

Heres my server:

```
import asyncore
import socket

class EchoHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def handle_read(self):
        data = self.recv(8192)
        if data:
            print "Recieved Data: ", data, ". This server address:", self.getsockname()

class EchoServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
            handler = EchoHandler(sock)

server = EchoServer('localhost', 56787)
server = EchoServer('localhost', 56788)
asyncore.loop()
```

Here are my clients:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 56787))
data = ""
while data.upper() != "Q":
 data = raw_input("Enter something to send to the server")
 s.send(data)
s.close()


import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 56788))
data = ""
while data.upper() != "Q":
 data = raw_input("Enter something to send to the server")
 s.send(data)
s.close()
```

This worked well, the python handled both ports. You should also be able to define seperate server classes for each of your ports.